# SQL Query to find linked records in a single table

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
ID   Customer Name   LinkedID
1    A        X      
2    B        Y      1
3    C        Z      2
```

I need to write a query that will:

```
1- For each ID (1,2,3)
2- If there is a LINKEDID defined (2,3 have links)
3- If the CUSTOMER of the LINKEDID is A
4- Return record for that ID
```

So in the above example it would do something like:

- ID's 2,3 have LinkedID's specified
- ID2 links to #1 which is customer A (good) return ID2
- ID3 links to #2 which is customer B (bad)

So the end result would be ID2.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE LINKED <> NULL    // this will get me the list
? But now how do I iterate over each of the results and compare the customers?
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE LINKED = 1` works?

Comment: Andrew - SQL Server...
IIya - Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join to the table twice. C is the primary table, P represents the parent table refereced by the linkedID.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    CustomerTable C
JOIN    CustomerTable P ON P.ID = C.LinkedID
WHERE   P.Customer = 'A'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.id
from your_table t1
inner join your_table t2 on t1.linkedid = t2.id
where t2.customer = 'A'
```